# Azure Data Lake: error copiando archivos a lago de almacén datos Azure (Azure Data Lake Store)

Tags: azure

Estoy tratando de mover nuestros archivos desde HDFS (configuré puerta de enlace de datos en máquina virtual de Azure) a Lago de almacén datos azure (Azure Data Lake Store).
Así que creé una fábrica de datos (con servicios vinculados, conjuntos de datos, puerta de enlace de datos y  canalización). canalización se crea con acción de copia.

Uno de los servicios vinculados elegimos "Azure Data Lake Store", configurado como muestro a continuación:

```
{
    "name": "AzureDataLakeStoreLinkedService",
    "properties": {
        "hubName": "xxxxxxxx_hub",
        "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
        "typeProperties": {
            "dataLakeStoreUri": "https://xxxxxx.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1",
            "authorization": "**********",
            "sessionId": "**********",
            "subscriptionId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "resourceGroupName": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Después de ejecutar la programación de la canalización muestra el siguiente error:

```
ErrorCode=UserErrorHdfsUnexpectedFileIO,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The request to 'HDFS' failed due to unexpected error,
Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=Unable to connect to the remote server,Source=System,
''Type=System.Net.Sockets.SocketException,Message=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,Source=System,'.
```

He establecido los siguientes grupos de acceso, pero esto no ha funcionado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]